# jQuery onclick Event call a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```js
function hvcm_wait() {
  waitingDialog.show('Please wait while your VM is rebooting...');
}

$('#hv_ConfirmShutDown').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Shutdown Now</a>
```

How do I call the javascript function hvcm_wait() when .btn-ok is clicked is clicked in Modal?

Any help would be highly apperciated. Thanks!

Comment: <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" onclick="hvcm_wait()">Shutdown Now</a> change your anchor tag with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this, first in the $() you search for the class btn-ok, then you hand it a onClick handler that executes the function.

```
$(".btn-ok").click(function(){
    hvcm_wait();
});
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. I used:

$( ".btn-ok" ).click(function() {
  $('#hv_ConfirmShutDown').modal('hide');
  waitingDialog.show('Please wait...');
});

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `.btn-ok` is not present when `script` is loaded, so use event-delegation.

Add these lines after `hvcm_wait()` function

```
$('#hv_ConfirmShutDown').on('click', '.btn-ok', function() {
    hvcm_wait();
})
```

Or if it is present in DOM then you can directly do this

```
$('.btn-ok').click(function() {
    hvcm_wait();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can add it straight to your HTML like this:

`<a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" onclick="hvcm_wait()">Shutdown Now</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding href attribute here. First you need to prevent the href and call the normal function.

```
 $(".btn-ok").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     hvcm_wait(); 
 });
```